# Applying a custom Inspector script on all objects of the same type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to custom editor scripts, and I stumbled upon a functionality that needs to be applied on all MonoBehavior scripts.

Tried `[CustomEditor(typeof(MonoBehavior))]`, but typeof is specific to the exact type, while I need it to be applied to all subclasses. Is there a way to make it apply to all subclasses of MonoBehavior?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. [Here's the documentation of the CustomEditor's constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CustomEditor-ctor.html)

**Edit:**

`[CustomEditor(typeof(MonoBehavior))]` can be used with parameter `editorForChildClasses`.

`editorForChildClasses`:    If true, child classes of inspectedType will also show this editor. Defaults to false.